# MySQL: Get the average of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name `invoices`. There is a column named `user` and `late_fee`. I am trying to find out the percentage of late invoices compared to how many invoices total.

He has 16 invoices, which 2 of those invoices are late. I feel like this should be an easy pie  query but I can't figure it out for the life of me?

Comment: Could you please provide the full table structure for the invoices table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like this. It gets the count of the `late_fee` depending on it's value.

```
select sum( case
            when late_fee = 1
            then 1
            else 0
            end
          )
        / count(*)
from    invoices
group
by      user
```

As @Ravinder pointed out, in MySQL this is also valid (does not work on other platforms though):

```
select sum( late_fee = 1
          )
        / count(*)
from    invoices
group
by      user
```

Comment: It can simply also be `sum( late_fee = 1 ) / count( * )`.

Comment: Yes. `Oracle` supports such expressions in `where` clause only.But `MySQL` supports at query level. Example @ [*MySql Fiddle*] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d41d8/571)

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Cool. Your first answer is generic. OP should go with that.